# Spring boot Rest service consumer app - SSL issues with Docker deployment

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, dockerfile

We have a Spring boot web app which consumes a third party REST API. Currently the third party API has exposed with the IP (No domain name mapped) and it's over https.

In our app, we disabled the host name verification checks and other few tweaks using below code. Then we could access the 3rd party API without any SSL issues.
This is our rest template config:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();

    Map valueMap = new HashMap<>();

    valueMap.put("Authorization", "Bearer ");
    valueMap.put("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    interceptors.add(new CalCustomInterceptor(valueMap));

    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
        .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf).setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

When we run the service (as a jar) in our dev server this works fine. However this is not working when the app runs inside a docker container. Any idea why is that?

UPDATE: Error coming while running inside docker container:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: What error does it gives when running inside docker ?

Comment: Updated the question with the exception details. Thanks.

Comment: @J4Priyan found any answers ?